# Angular Material Dialog & JSON.stringify

Tags: json, angular, angular-material, dialog, stringify

I am unable to show the string provided by JSON.stringify including the spaces for indentation **inside a material dialog** of my Angular project. It always appears as a raw data string, without any spacing for the indentation, even if I use the spaces parameter.
The funny thing is that the same code provides a good indentation if I *console.log* it.

component.ts :

```
[...]
onClickJSON() {
    let dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig()
    dialogConfig.data = {
        json: this.item
    }
this.jsonDialog.open(JsonDialogComponent, dialogConfig)
[...]
```

dialog.ts :

```
[...]
export class JsonDialogComponent implements OnInit {

    json: string;

    constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<JsonDialogComponent>,
                @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data['json'], null, 4)) //Good appearance
    this.json = JSON.stringify(this.data['json'], null, 4) //Bad appearance, like raw data
[...]
```

dialog.html :

```
<p>
    {{json}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't use the correct tag.

Instead of using `<p>`, use either

```html
<pre>{{ json }}</pre>
```

or

```html
<pre><code>{{ json }}<code></pre>
```

More in depth, this is due to CSS styling, you can check the native styling of the `pre` tag and apply it to your `p` if you want. But semantically speaking, it's better to use `<pre>` than `<p>` in that case.

Comment: Thanks it works, I was not aware about the <pre> tag

Comment: No problem, if it resolved your issue be sure to mark it as such !

Comment: yeah... just in 5 min it will let me do so, you were so fast :D
BR